# Accessing another view from a button's onclick event

Tags: android, android-animation

I am developing a simple game and in an activity I have 2 image buttons:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:onClick="btn1_click" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:onClick="btn2_click" />
```

And I am showing some animations when buttons are clicked:

```
public void btn1_click(View v) {
    v.startAnimation(animLeftTranslate);
}
public void btn2_click(View v) {
    v.startAnimation(animRightTranslate);
}
```

Of course, only the clicked button is being animated but what I want to do is **to show animation for both two buttons** when one of them are clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by your own approach i.e. using `android:onClick` attribute:

Assign one function to both `ImageButton` for example `btns_clicked()`. So add `android:onClick='btns_clicked'` to both your buttons. And in that function write:

```
public void btns_clicked(View v) {
    View btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    View btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);

    btn1.startAnimation(animLeftTranslate);
    btn2.startAnimation(animRightTranslate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `android:onClick`, you can do it in java code:

```
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt2);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn1.startAnimation(animRightTranslate);
            btn2.startAnimation(animRightTranslate);
        }
    };
    btn1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(listener);`
```

`

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem but @ABFORCE 's answer is matched better with my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as describe below.

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"
    android:onClick="btn_click" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/img2"
    android:onClick="btn_click" />
```

and in activity, you have to use

```
public void btn_click(View v) {
if(v.getId() == R.id.btn1)
    v.startAnimation(animLeftTranslate);
else if(v.getId() == R.id.btn2)
    v.startAnimation(animRightTranslate);
}
```